# Python - 'IPv4Address' is not defined

Tags: python, ip-address

Here is a part of Python script

```
import ipaddr, ipaddress

if ((IPv4Address(lower_ip) <= sender-ip) and (IPv4Address(upper_ip) >= sender-ip)):
        print "in range"
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "namelookup3.py", line 55, in <module>
    if ((IPv4Address(lower_ip) <= sender-ip) and (IPv4Address(upper_ip) >= sende
r-ip)):
NameError: name 'IPv4Address' is not defined
```

I imported ipaddr and ipaddress, and %PATH% is set to D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages which has the Compiled Python File of both ipaddr and ipaddress

HELP!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: My educated guess is that you come from a C background: `import` is nothing like `#include`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `import` a module, you must prefix all objects in the module with their namespace, like:

```
import ipaddr, ipaddress

if ((ipaddress.IPv4Address(lower_ip) <= sender_ip) and (ipaddress.IPv4Address(upper_ip) >= sender-ip)):
        print "in range"
```

Alternatively, you can import the `IPv4Address` class directly in current namespace with:

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Address

if ((IPv4Address(lower_ip) <= sender_ip) and (IPv4Address(upper_ip) >= sender_ip)):
        print "in range"
```

Besides, you will probably want to replace `sender-ip` with `sender_ip`.